# Can we map product category to Customer/Store in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

In Magento, We can able to map the customers to the website. Is it possible to map the customers to the product category or the particular store ?

Note: Each product category has to be mapped with certain group of customer. All the products should not be visible to all the customer.

How can we achieve this.

Comment: below comment is helpful to you..

Answer (score 0):

I have the same requirement on my current project ended up going with this

https://github.com/Vinai/groupscatalog2

It seems like the solution is pretty heavy but, this was the most no fuss solution and it does the trick